# IMAGE from Google Drive in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive, formulas, images

I have the following image on a cell in my Google Sheets:

```
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1C9KL2vEhnZOVdCe2qUG5MZomw3jpvCiX
```

When I use the formula `=IMAGE(A1)`, the cell with the image stays white...

Any idea how to make it work?

PS. A1 is where the text with the URL is included.

Answer (score 0):

- ## change **`open`** to **`uc`** in your link and then use **`=IMAGE(B3)`**:

[image: 1]

- **note:** image can't be private